# WordPress database error: [Duplicate entry '0' for key '0c0_gf_form_view.PRIMARY']

Tags: wordpress

I am facing this error when on my WordPress website

WordPress database error: [Duplicate entry '0' for key '0c0_gf_form_view.PRIMARY']

WordPress database error: [Duplicate entry '0' for key '0c0_gf_entry.PRIMARY']

anyone can help with that